# Formsauthentication should be disabled for a single page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, forms-authentication, formsauthentication

I have a problem with Formsauthentication and my ajax calls.
I like the way Formsauthenticaction works for a normal asp.net website.

However I have a page in my asp.net website which gets called using AJAX. This page will in some case set the Response StatusCode to Unauthorized (401).

```
Response.StatusCode = 401;
Response.End();
```

Now the Response should end and I would like to see this 401 statuscode propagated to the frontend. However Formsauthentication decides otherwise and changes this status to a 302 and redirects to the loginpage.
Thus I can not check for status 401 on my UI.

To inform you further: I am running an asp.net 4.0 website (**Not** MVC) on IIS 7.

I tried configuring my web.config with following node:

```
<location path="mypage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

But I guess by setting the Unauthorized status triggers the Formsauthentication module nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few proposed solutions from [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/articles/AboutHaacked.aspx).

[Prevent Forms Authentication Login Page Redirect When You Don’t Want It](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx)

Comment: nice read, I think in my scenario the 'DoNotRedirectLoginModule' is the correct approach. Thanks a lot for this extremely useful answer.